# Dynamic value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have:

```
function saved() {
    $('#linha_1').append('<div class="salvo"><img width=20 height=20 src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/check1.png"></div>'); 
}
```

My forms are generated in dynamic loops with different ids (not only `#linha_1` but `#linha_2` etc). How can I make my button :

```
<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' onclick='saved();'>
```

pass the correct id to my Javascript? So instead of `$('#linha_1')` I can have a dynamic value? in my case I use `linha_$events[0]` to generate the `div` ID I want to append...

forms loop :

```
<form action='http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/insert_wallet.php' method='post' target='hidden-form'>



  <input type='checkbox' name='pago'   value='yes' <?php if ($che=='yes') {echo "checked='yes'";} else if ($cccc='') {} else {} ; ?> > <br> </div><div class='tb1_small sc' >
  <input type='checkbox' name='recibo'   value='yes' <?php if ($rec=='yes') {echo "checked='yes'";} else{}; ?>  > <br></div><div class='tb3_md sc '>
 <input type="hidden" name="contador"  readonly value="<?php  echo $id_postt1."linha_".$events[0];  ?>"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="id_p"  readonly value="<?php  echo $events[2];?>"> 
  <input type='Submit' value='Salvar' class='my-form'  onclick='saved();'>
</form> 
</div></div>
```

Comment: Did you try with `$( this ) ` ?

Comment: Show your HTML with `#linha_1`.

Comment: Don't use incremental id attributes - instead traverse the DOM to find the relevant `form` element to the clicked button and find the needed information from there: `$(this).closest('form').find(...);`

Comment: didnt work with $(this) on my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
function saved(id) {  // receive id of the form on which saved is clicked
    $('#linha_'+ id).append('<div class="salvo"><img width=20 height=20 src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/check1.png"></div>'); 
}
```

In each loop do it like this :

```
<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' onclick='saved(<?php echo $events[0]); ?>'> // pass id of the form to javascript function here
```

Comment: didnt worked... im guessing becouse the $events[0]; value is only valid on each loop than it changes

Comment: html should be `<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' onclick='saved(1)'  />

Comment: saved is not defined

Comment: define saved on top of your view file

Comment: its on the top but still no joy

Comment: weird. can you post your updated code? so i can have a look or the html being rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99818/discussion-between-noor-and-i-am-sam).

Comment: tks noor ... u can see it in :https://www.dropbox.com/s/2icghxr5ejict8n/single-wallet.php?dl=0

Comment: around line 237 theres the forms loop and on line 22 the script on line 213 i have the variable div id on wich i want to create the new div on

Comment: I have read the code and it looks fine. what is the html output of the above code?

Comment: no function saved is rendered in the html also there is no onclick event here `<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' class='my-form'  '>`

Comment: sorry i changed my code back to yours.. now it works only on the first form becouse i passing id 1 so it reads #linha_1 but it must be dinamic

Comment: there are multiple mistakes in your code.. firstly i got this error `ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
<script>new WOW().init();</script>
` secondly you are passing linda_1 instead of 1 here `<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' onclick='saved(linha_1)' />`

Comment: come to chat i will explain it to you

Comment: i get it to work based on ur code like this :  <input type='Submit' value='Salvar' onclick='saved(<?php echo $fid ?>)' />  and $fid=linha_$events[0]  tks alot man

Comment: exactly i asked you to do so in first attempt

Comment: @I-amSam checked your html code. its ok now .. best of luck

Comment: ur right ! i must did something wrong the first time .. i also changed the  script to  $( id).append :) tks 4 all the help  :)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be not to use ID's, but classes:

```
<form id="form_1" class="my-form">
    <!-- ... -->
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
...
<form id="form_n" class="my-form">
    <!-- ... -->
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('.my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // remove this if your are not using ajax form handlers...

    // handle the submission as you want... To get the form id, do:
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).append('<div class="salvo"><img width=20 height=20 src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/check1.png"></div>');
});
```

Comment: somehow dident work .. im submiting via hidden iframe on page maybe thats why ?

Comment: Please update your question with more details about how you are doing this. Include the code to your forms and the iframe structure.

Comment: i tried that ... some how the script is invalid i get SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: Have you added the `class` attribute to all your forms?

Comment: Your problem is that you are putting form elements outside the `<form>` tag. You have to move all them inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use separate function and call it using `on*` attributes. Instead, use it unobtrusively. Give a class to the `<input>` say, `form-submit`:

```
<input type='Submit' value='Salvar' class='form-submit' />
```

And then call it like this:

```
$('.form-submit').closest('form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).append('<div class="salvo"><img width=20 height=20 src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/check1.png"></div>');
});
```

Comment: @I-amSam You should have informed that.

Comment: @I-amSam Banned for what?

Comment: im guessing i got more votes down than votes up on my questions